# Why I am getting undefined in console

Tags: javascript

```js
const horn = () => {
  console.log("Toot");
};
console.log(horn());
```

I am getting the output as

Toot
undefined

But I can't understand why it is so

Comment: Because you're logging the result of `horn` which is nothing /`undefined`?

Answer (score 6):

Your horn function does not return anything ...

```js
const horn = () => {
  return 'horn';
};
const horn2 = () => {
  console.log('horn');
};
console.log(horn());
horn2();
```

Answer (score 3):

[return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Description)

> If the value is omitted, undefined is returned instead.

Your function does not *return* anything. If a function does not *return* anything then by default `undefined` is returned.

```js
const horn = () => {
  console.log("Toot");
  return "Toot";
};
console.log(horn());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're function is not returning any values.

```
const horn = () => {
  console.log("Toot");// <-- problem
};
```

It should be like this

```
const horn = () => {
  return "Toot";
};
```

console.log(horn());

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` can be remove if you return something in `horn()` function

```js
const horn = () => {
      return "Toot";
    };
console.log(horn());
```